# Performance issue with paging FragmentStatePagerAdapter and GridView with images

Tags: android, android-fragments, lazy-loading, android-gridview, android-pageradapter

I have an page with arrows, by clicking on each arrow I move to next page with grid and images there (the images were downloaded before entering to the page).

I have an performance issue that at the beginning before I run over all the collection of pages and load the images into the memory the page change is made slowly because of the images load. I wanted to ask if you have any ideas how to fix it:

So  I have an `PageAdapter`  that extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` .
There I'm creating a `page` that extends `BaseFragment`and in every `page` I create instance of `GridAdapter` that extends `BaseAdapter` and responsible for the images drawing in the `GridView`. I don't work directly with the `GridAdapter` because I need to return to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` an `fragment` for the paging.

When I creating `GridAdapter` for each page I create the `viewHolder`:

```
private MyViewHolders createHolder() {
        MyViewHolders holder = new MyViewHolders();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(fragment.getActivity())
                .inflate(R.layout.cust_layout, null);
        holder.layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Rlayout);
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainIMage);
        return holder;
    }
```

and In `getView`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CarData carD = getCarItem(position);
        MyViewHolders viewHolder = getViewHolder (carD.id);

        viewHolder.carImage.setImageDrawable(carD.image);
        convertView = viewHolder.layout;
        return convertView;
    }
```

It all loads with 1 sec delay, after I browsed all the pages it start to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to you is that you basically run afoul of the way the view pager handlers page loading synchronously. The call to

```
viewHolder.carImage.setImageDrawable(carD.image);
```

constructs a `Drawable` from the image stored in the applications assets. This is done synchronously, i.e. the application needs to wait for it. This drawable is cached as long as the image heap is not exhausted. When you add more fragments/pages, the delay probably re-appears even when you have already viewed all pages as image data gets purged to make room for other images.

The "solution" depends on what you find acceptable for you application:

- You can try to reduce the size of your images. Note that image format is also important.
- You can switch to lazy image loading using a third party library like [picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) which will load your images in the background. This will increase responsiveness for your application at the cost of making each image appear one by one as it gets loaded.
- A ton of more options including layout changes and pre-rendering and storing the whole page as a bitmap.